# Growing arrays. Refer to the elements by pointers, not indexes

Tags: c

Since the array address may change when memory is reallocated,
the main part of the program (in the body of the function main ()) should refer to the elements by
indexes, not pointers. Why? 
Can you show an example of accessing items with pointers?
(Sorry for my English).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Nameval Nameval;

struct Nameval {
    char *name;
    int value;
};

struct NVtab {
    int nval;         /* current number of values */ 
    int max;          /* allocated number of values */
    Nameval *nameval; /* array of name-value pairs */
};

enum {NVINIT = 1, NVGROW = 2};

/* addname: add new name and value to nvtab */
int addname(struct NVtab *nvtab, Nameval newname) {
    Nameval *nvp;
    if (nvtab->nameval == NULL) { /* first time */
        nvtab->nameval = (Nameval *) malloc(NVINIT * sizeof(Nameval));
        if (nvtab->nameval == NULL) 
            return -1;
        nvtab->max = NVINIT;
        nvtab->nval = 0;
    } else if (nvtab->nval >= nvtab->max) { /* grow */
        nvp = (Nameval *) realloc(nvtab->nameval,
                                  (NVGROW*nvtab->max)*sizeof(Nameval));
        if (nvp == NULL)
            return -1;
        nvtab->max *= NVGROW;
        nvtab->nameval = nvp;

    }
    nvtab->nameval[nvtab->nval] = newname;
    return nvtab->nval++;
}

int main(void) {
    struct NVtab nvtab = {0, 0, NULL};

    int curnum;
    curnum = addname(&nvtab, (Nameval) {.name="Andy", .value=12});
    printf("%d\n", curnum);
    curnum = addname(&nvtab, (Nameval) {.name="Billy", .value=18});
    printf("%d\n", curnum);
    curnum = addname(&nvtab, (Nameval) {.name="Jack", .value=71});
    printf("%d\n", curnum);
    for (int i = 0; i < nvtab.nval; i++) {
        printf("%s %d\n", nvtab.nameval[i].name,
                          nvtab.nameval[i].value);
    }
}
```

For example, why can`t we show array like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nvtab.nval; i++)
    printf("%s %d\n", nvtab.*(nameval+i).name, nvtab.*(nameval+i).value);
```

Comment: The very first sentence does not make sense. Pointers are very valid way to access array elements.  The code seem to be too complicated to illustrate your problem as articulated.

Comment: The reason to access the array by index is that after calling `realloc` the array can be at a completely different location. So any pointers stored before then become invalid, but an array index stored remains valid. For example, you might be tracking the largest value in the array. BTW the question title says the opposite of the question body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to assign a pointer calculated for a specific index to a variable with storage duration which could extend over an insert operation.

That pointer could become invalid, so the lesson behind that example is to always re-evaluate iterators on dynamic data structures.

E.g. what ***not*** to do:

```
auto *foo = &nvtab.nameval[i];
addname(&nvtab, (Nameval) {.name="Billy", .value=18});
printf("%s %d\n", foo->name, foo->value);
```

In the last line it can work or crash. Depending on whether `realloc` moved the allocation or resized in-place. Except that you can never know for sure until you execute it, as it isn't even fully deterministic.

Comment: I rewrite first row like this:                                                                                                                                                 `Nameval *foo = &nvtab.nameval[0];`                                                    And `printf("%s %d\n", foo->name, foo->value);` always prints  0-th item of nvtab after adding new items. Does it mean that realloc does`t move the allocation?

Comment: @АндрійПродан Yes, it does. Usually the allocation is only moved once it exceeds a certain size limit. As long as there is spare address space behind the original pointer it's just extended. Try executing the 2nd and 3rd line together in a loop. It should crash eventually. (And do it in "Debug" build, in optimized builds memory may be left intact even after `realloc` freed it.)

Answer (score 1):

This is not valid syntax:

```
nvtab. *(nameval+i).name
```

The member access operator `.` expects to be followed by the name of the member.  What you want is:

```
 (*(nvtab.nameval+i)).name
```